# Why would I segfault while removing from a list?

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove an object from a list if it meets certain criteria in C++11 and then return true if the object was found:

```
int x = 178;
typename network_internal_edge_store_type::iterator itr =
    internal_edges.begin();
for (; itr != internal_edges.end(); ++itr) {
  // If edge object found that has this property, then remove it.
  if (itr->index1() == x || itr->index2() == x) {
    itr = internal_edges.erase(itr);
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

However, this segfaults on the line `itr = internal_edges.erase(itr);`. `internal_edges` is a list of shared pointers of objects representing edges in a network that I defined above.

At first I thought I was dereferencing an invalid iterator, so I set a breakpoint at that line. To my surprise, the iterator seemed valid when I dereferenced it as a watch expression (`*itr`).

Then, I thought that the trouble may stem from how the iterator points to a shared pointer, so I tried `itr->reset()` before `itr = internal_edges.erase(itr);`, but the program then segfaults on the line `itr->reset()`.

What else could cause this segfault?

Here's more info on the type of `internal_edges`.

```
class NetworkInternalEdge;
typedef NetworkInternalEdge network_internal_edge_type;
typedef std::weak_ptr< network_internal_edge_type > network_weak_edge_ptr;
typedef std::shared_ptr< network_internal_edge_type > network_shared_edge_ptr;
typedef std::list< network_shared_edge_ptr > network_internal_edge_store_type;
network_internal_edge_store_type internal_edges;
```

== Tracing the error ==

I'm still trying to reproduce this error with a small test case. I also realized that the error relates to the line `_M_dispose();` (line 147) in shared_ptr_base.h:

```
      void
  _M_release() noexcept
  {
    // Be race-detector-friendly.  For more info see bits/c++config.
    _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_BEFORE(&_M_use_count);
if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(&_M_use_count, -1) == 1)
  {
        _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_AFTER(&_M_use_count);
    _M_dispose();
    // There must be a memory barrier between dispose() and destroy()
    // to ensure that the effects of dispose() are observed in the
    // thread that runs destroy().
    // See http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2005-11/msg00136.html
    if (_Mutex_base<_Lp>::_S_need_barriers)
      {
```

It seems that something is up with the shared pointers. At the time of erasing, there exist 1 shared and 3 weak pointers that point to `**itr`. Does that help?

Comment: UB could cause it. Without an actual testcase that we can compile and run for ourselves, everything beyond that is pure guessing.

Comment: Just a question, what is the point of assignment if you're returning immediately? I mean `itr = internal_edges.erase(itr);` could be written as `internal_edges.erase(itr);`. Usually assignment is done when you're still inside the loop, in which case you don't increment iterator in the `for`, rather you do it in the `else` block.

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of `itr =`. It still segfaults though. This function is part of a bigger code base.. let me see if I can make a smaller test case...

Comment: @DavidFaux: Next question, what is the type of `internal_edges`? If you've written it, then you must show us. In general you should tell us about types of each variable you use in your question.

Comment: Have you tried to trace a bit more? In particular it's of interest whether it segfaults in the destructor of your edge object or in the actual erase function.

Comment: PlasmaHH has a very good point, but I would like to explain it a bit further. Any undefined behavior that you invoke anywhere earlier in your program might have messed up with the memory layout of your list or the smart pointers held by it. That's why you need an isolated test case.

Comment: internal_edges.erase(itr) will make itr++ cannot find itr->next. But you return true so I think it is not this problem. Can you add a itr-- after internal_edges.erase(itr)?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question a bit. I traced the error to a file related to shared pointers. And it seems that my function returns immediately. `--itr` doesn't change anything I think.

Comment: Is there a realy need to keep `weak_ptr` inside `shared_ptr` ? Maybe it would be enough to do so: `typedef std::shared_ptr< network_internal_edge_type > network_shared_edge_ptr;` ?

Comment: It looks to me like either the shared pointer itself or the object owned by it has become corrupted somehow. Unfortunately, that could have happened at just about any time before this.